# Save Value for DB Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to create a Report where a Device Count is displayed for this Month and the last month.
In my DB only the current device count is saved, so my idea was to export the columns to a new reporting db.
Is this he best approach or is there an easier way to display my device count from last month?

An example from my Report

```
Name(Table) DeviceCount(View) CLientCategoryName(Table)
First       5                 Computer
```

Comment: what is you schema, sample data and expected result?

Comment: So you're only tracking one instance of the device at a time. You can do this multiple ways. Add a date field for the device count and you'd have a historical record. Another option is to do what you said, create another table and store historical records everytime you update the current one.

Comment: I have a application with devices and I'm building a report from two tables and a view. So i have TenantName, ClientCategory (from my tables) and DeviceCount from an existing View. I would rather not write anything in the productive Database.